How do I change the color of a slot?
I do this litegraph.js test node
class CustomConstSpecialNumber {
    constructor() {
        this.title = "Const Special";
        this.desc = "Constant special";
        this.color = '#222234'
        this.bgcolor = '#333257'
        this.addOutput("value", "special", {color: "#DDDD"});
        this.addProperty("value", 1.0);
    }
    onExecute() {
        this.setOutputData(0, this.properties["value"]);
    }
}

but the output slot color is always green:

Is it possible to change the color of the slot? If yes, how?

The solution is to use LGraphCanvas.default_connection_color_byType.
Definition: litegraph.js
        this.default_connection_color_byType = {
            /*number: "#7F7",
            string: "#77F",
            boolean: "#F77",*/
        }
        this.default_connection_color_byTypeOff = {
            /*number: "#474",
            string: "#447",
            boolean: "#744",*/
        };


Here is how i managed to set default pin & stroke (link) colors by type
   * Initializes the graph and canvas.
   * @param canvasElement - The HTMLCanvasElement to initialize LiteGraphCanvas with.
   */
  const initializeGraph = (canvasElement: HTMLCanvasElement): void => {
    const customLinkTypeColors = {
        integer: "#d2ffb0",
        string: "#f3b0ff",
        boolean: "#F77",
        float: "#b0e0ff",
        column: "#fffdb0"
    };
    
    graph.value = new LGraph()
    graphCanvas.value = new LGraphCanvas(canvasElement, graph.value)

    graphCanvas.value.default_connection_color_byType  = customLinkTypeColors
    graphCanvas.value.default_connection_color_byTypeOff  = customLinkTypeColors

    Object.assign(LGraphCanvas.link_type_colors, customLinkTypeColors);

    graph.value.start()
  }

And the result:
enter image description here
